# Async fields generation and TextureRegion rendering problem

Tags: libgdx, libktx

I have a piece of code to render a grid from which I will render a maze.
My build function:

```
fun buildAsync(): Deferred<RegularMaze> {
        return KtxAsync.async(newSingleThreadAsyncContext()) {
            addEmptyFields()
            enableLeftBordersRender()
            enableBottomBordersRender()

            regularMazeService.convertFieldsToMaze(fields, colsNo, rowsNo)
        }
    }
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

But when I move `addEmptyFields()` before `async` section it is rendering correctly
[image]

And my `Wall` class

```
class Wall (width: Float, height: Float, x: Float = 0F, y: Float = 0F, rotation: Float = 0F) : BasePart() {

    private val textureRegion: TextureRegion
    private val size: Size = Size(width, height)
    private val position: Position = Position(x, y, rotation)

    var relatedFieldIndex: Int? = null

    var shouldBeDraw = true

    init {
        inject()

        val wallTexture = assetsHelper.getTextureFromAsset(TextureAsset.WALL)
        wallTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat)
        textureRegion = TextureRegion(wallTexture, 0, 0, size.widthInt, size.heightInt)

        setBounds(
            position.x,
            position.y,
            width,
            height
        )

        rotateBy(position.rotation)
    }

    override fun draw(batch: Batch, parentAlpha: Float) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha)
        if (shouldBeDraw) {
            batch.draw(textureRegion, position.x, position.y, 0F, 0F, size.width, size.height, 1F, 1F, position.rotation)
        }
    }

    class Size (val width: Float, val height: Float) {
        val widthInt: Int
            get() = ceil(width).toInt()

        val heightInt: Int
            get() = ceil(height).toInt()
    }

    data class Position(val x: Float, val y: Float, val rotation: Float)
}
```

**[EDIT/UPDATE]**

I discover something strange, when I create a single `Wall` without dimensions before `async` it starts working. "Working" code:

```
fun buildAsync(): Deferred<RegularMaze> {
        Wall(0f,0f) // <---- new line
        return KtxAsync.async(newSingleThreadAsyncContext()) {
            addEmptyFields()
            enableLeftBordersRender()
            enableBottomBordersRender()

            regularMazeService.convertFieldsToMaze(fields, colsNo, rowsNo)
        }
    }
```

**Why?**

Comment: Is this line `assetsHelper.getTextureFromAsset(TextureAsset.WALL)` lazily instantiating a Texture? You cannot load textures from background threads. This would explain why instantiating a Wall first (on the game thread) fixes it.

Comment: Feel free to use [KTX GitHub issues](https://github.com/libktx/ktx/issues) if you want to discuss any parts of the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into concurrency issues. The "fixed" code probably works by accident due to a slight delay in executing the coroutine or performing some crucial operation on the main thread, not because it addresses the actual problem.

As a rule of thumb, you should never modify anything that is accessed by the rendering thread on different thread pools. My guess is that something modifies or accesses the `regularMazeService` while the coroutine is being executed, or the `assetsHelper.getTextureFromAsset(TextureAsset.WALL)` fails to load the texture in a background thread as it lacks the OpenGL context.

If there is some expensive part of the operation that you want to do on a separate thread - that's OK, but anything that modifies the state of the rendering thread should be done *on* the rendering thread. For example:

```kotlin
fun buildAsync(): Deferred<RegularMaze> {
    return KtxAsync.async(asyncContext) {
        onRenderingThread {
            addEmptyFields()
        }
        enableLeftBordersRender()
        enableBottomBordersRender()

        regularMazeService.convertFieldsToMaze(fields, colsNo, rowsNo)
    }
}
```

If any part of your code executed via coroutine launched with a custom thread:

- Needs access to OpenGL context (e.g. texture loading).
- Accesses or modifies data from the rendering thread.
- Performs any kind of rendering or updates relying on the rendering delta time.

You should move it into the `onRenderingThread` block.

Also, you should reuse coroutine contexts. Do not start a new thread for each coroutine with `newSingleThreadAsyncContext()` - assign the `AsyncContext` and reuse its instance.

---

If you are loading textures manually, I encourage you to use the `AssetStorage` available in [`ktx-assets-async`](https://github.com/libktx/ktx/tree/master/assets-async) module. It leverages coroutines for true parallel asset loading.